# Rust complains of conflicting lifetime requirements, no iterators or closures

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to teach myself Rust.  I'm familiar with C++ and Scala, but Rust is still a Perlish language to me.

I've been bickering with the borrow checker for two days over this code.  It seems pretty clear to me, but I can't get Rust to agree.

This is about as simple as I can get the code and still produce the error:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut streams: StdStreams = StdStreams {
        stderr: &mut io::stderr(),
    };
    let command = Command {};
    let streams_ref: &mut StdStreams = &mut streams;
    command.go(streams_ref);
}

pub struct StdStreams<'a> {
    stderr: &'a mut io::Write,
}

pub struct Command {}

impl Command {
    pub fn go(&self, streams: &mut ::StdStreams) {
        let mut server = Server { streams };
    }
}

pub struct Server<'a> {
    pub streams: &'a mut StdStreams<'a>,
}
```

Here's the compiler's opinion:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:26
   |
20 |         let mut server = Server { streams };
   |                          ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the method body at 19:5...
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 | /     pub fn go(&self, streams: &mut ::StdStreams) {
20 | |         let mut server = Server { streams };
21 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:35
   |
20 |         let mut server = Server { streams };
   |                                   ^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method body at 19:5...
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 | /     pub fn go(&self, streams: &mut ::StdStreams) {
20 | |         let mut server = Server { streams };
21 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected &mut StdStreams<'_>, found &mut StdStreams<'_>)
  --> src/main.rs:20:35
   |
20 |         let mut server = Server { streams };
   |                                   ^^^^^^^
```

It seems clear to me that the item I'm storing the offending reference in will go out of scope and die immediately, at the same moment its stored reference does, so there shouldn't be any unpleasantness.

I also find this needlessly sarcastic: `expected &mut StdStreams<'_>, found &mut StdStreams<'_>`.

Comment: You can see [my original answer](https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/c7f7df8f82827fee3daa2e6f4f9897d0) before I marked it as a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue becomes clearer when we see how the compiler makes all lifetimes explicit in the `go` method:

```
pub fn go<'a, 'b, 'c>(&'a self, streams: &'b mut StdStreams<'c>) {
    let mut server = Server {streams};
}
```

That's right, a lifetime parameter was missing. The compiler does not infer that the lifetime parameter `'a` in `StdStreams<'a>` will be the same as the lifetime of a reference of type `&mut StdStreams` (as in, it won't produce `&'a Foo<'a>`. The compiler will also use these named lifetimes in its error messages where possible:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:20:26
   |
20 |         let mut server = Server {streams};
   |                          ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'b as defined on the method body at 19:5...
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 | /     pub fn go<'a, 'b, 'c>(&'a self, streams: &'b mut StdStreams<'c>) {
20 | |         let mut server = Server {streams};
21 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:34
   |
20 |         let mut server = Server {streams};
   |                                  ^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'c as defined on the method body at 19:5...
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 | /     pub fn go<'a, 'b, 'c>(&'a self, streams: &'b mut StdStreams<'c>) {
20 | |         let mut server = Server {streams};
21 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected &mut StdStreams<'_>, found &mut StdStreams<'c>)
  --> src/main.rs:20:34
   |
20 |         let mut server = Server {streams};
   |                                  ^^^^^^^
```

The conflict should now be clear: `'b` needs to outlive the lifetime `'c`, but the method does not impose that constraint. So, we can either bind the lifetime parameter to the same lifetime as the reference:

```
pub fn go<'a>(&self, streams: &'a mut StdStreams<'a>) {
}
```

Or add a constraint to the lifetime parameter.

```
pub fn go<'a: 'b, 'b>(&self, streams: &'a mut StdStreams<'b>) {
}
```

---

> I also find this needlessly sarcastic: expected `&mut StdStreams<'_>`, found `&mut StdStreams<'_>`

That is something that the compiler could probably improve on, but anonymous lifetimes are not that easy to express to the user.

Comment: Thanks.  That fixed my simplified version, and I was able to extrapolate a fix for the real version from the simplified version.  I appreciate it.  Nice job.